# Exit infinite while loop (python) when user enters "exit", but if users enters a number compare it to 50

Tags: python, while-loop, control-flow

i need help with this problem. ask user to enter a number inside an infinite while loop, compare this number to let say 50 (less, greater or equal). but in order to exit this while loop user must enter "exit". i have the following code that is working according to requirement but i want 'exit' (if) statement to be written at the end. doing so definitely causes an error. please feel free for alternative ways.

```
while True:
x = input('please enter a number to compare or enter "exit" to exit the loop \n')
if x == "exit":
    exit()
elif int(x) > 50:
    print(x, 'is greater than 50')
elif int(x) < 50:
    print(x, 'is less than 50')
else:
    print('the number you entered is 50')
```

Comment: There are lots of inputs here that will cause errors as well; the only non-integer argument you filter out before calling `int(x)` is the string `exit`.

Comment: You can't put the `exit` case at the end, because you have to ensure that `"exit"` isn't passed to `int`.

Comment: If you use `break` instead of `exit()` this code runs fine, barring other string input than 'exit'

Comment: @G.Anderson yes it works that way but what can you do when your instructor wants you to explicitly ask to enter exit :P,

Comment: Apologies, I failed at reading!

Comment: @chepner yes that's right, i got this question in an assignment and it was explicitly asked to enter 'exit' to leave the loop, other than that it is working fine with try and except

Comment: @G.Anderson no problem dude, i just ask for suggestions and all of them are valuable including yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what happens if the user types `fkljhae`? A `ValueError` is raised. And... hang on! This is raised for any non-`int` input - `"exit"` satisfies this criterion.

```
from sys import exit

while True:
    x = input('please enter a number to compare or enter "exit" to exit the loop \n')
    try:
        if int(x) > 50:
            print(x, 'is greater than 50')
        elif int(x) < 50:
            print(x, 'is less than 50')
        else:
            print('the number you entered is 50')
    except ValueError:
        if x == "exit":
            exit()
```

This isn't particularly good, though; what if `print` raises a `ValueError`? Let's refactor it so that only `int(x)` is in the `try:` `except:` block:

```
from sys import exit

while True:
    text = input('please enter a number to compare or enter "exit" to exit the loop \n')
    try:
        x = int(text)
    except ValueError:
        if text == "exit":
            exit()
    else:
        if x > 50:
            print(x, 'is greater than 50')
        elif x < 50:
            print(x, 'is less than 50')
        else:
            print('the number you entered is 50')
```

This is better, though `"exit"` isn't at the bottom any more.

Comment: yes it works with try and except 
but if there is any other string then it shows no error and i doesn't exit, i guess that's out of requirement as i mention explicitly to enter 'exit' to leave the loop

Comment: I'd refactor a bit. There's a lot of code in the `try` block, and the only thing that can raise the exception you are interested in is the call to `int`. (Granted, there's nothing else that *can* raise a `ValueError` in this case, so you aren't masking any other exceptions, but in principle, you want to keep the `try` block as focused as possible.)

Comment: @chepner Correct. However, that doesn't put `"exit"` last... I'll post a better version, too.

Comment: @jahanzaibyounis You can only accept one answer; the "tick" should go to the answer that answers the question best. You can upvote multiple answers. (Just so you know; I noticed that you clicked both. It's fine to accept another answer, if you feel that it answered your question better.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 that was a mistake i clicked both, your answer is much more explained and surely helped me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying to parse "exit" which is string to int
You can use try and except.